# pdf with links to different books / folders

Tags: pdf

I hv received pdf  with links to tv shows on tv;

- another pdf with links to different books (stored in google drive.)
  So you click on the picture  and it takes you to the pdf book and opens it.
  I have many learning books in my drive. I want to make a pdf with links to the books.
  How can I create a Pdf with links to these? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix its errors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating a document with either Microsoft Word or [Google Docs](https://drive.google.com) (which behaves the same as Microsoft Word in this regard).

1. Type a line of text in your document, such as "Python Programming Book".
2. Highlight the text you just wrote.
3. Enter Ctrl-k on your keyboard. That will open a window for you to enter a URL.
4. Enter the URL in the appropriate field of the window that opened.
5. Click [Apply] or [OK] or whatever the button is to apply your link.
6. Save your document as a PDF. In MS Word, choose File --> Save As and select the file type as PDF before you save. In Google Docs, choose File --> Download --> PDF Document